# PowerBI lat-long resolution is 2 digits

Tags: powerbi, gis, precision

We are using latitude-longitude co-ords with 6 decimal places draw heat maps on industrial estates.

It seems that PowerBI cuts off our last 4 digits and uses only two digits, rendering it useless for our application.

Is this the case? Does anyone know of a fix or what other GIS mapping tools we should use? We know about commercial products but the cost is prohibitive for our community noise monitoring budget.

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but it may help to add more details: 1. What data source are you using (excel? SQL Server?) What data type are the co ords in your data source? What data type is being used within the Power BI data model?

Comment: Data source currently Excel, the lat/long data has 8 decimal places in table view. The lat/long data has 'general' format.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but here are some things to try: 1. Export excel to CSV and import that instead; 2. Explicitly set the format to 6 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

PowerBI clearly doesn't restrict the latitude-longitude resolution to 2 digits. None of my map visuals would work with this. If you are seeing 2 digits only

1. Check the formatting:
   Column format should be decimal number, not text
   Column categeory should be latitude/longitude
2. Check your PowerQuery import script
3. Check your data source

Comment: That's a relief. 
Are you using PowerBI Pro?
I'll follow your advice and let you know how it goes.